# Export Data from Influx db as csv

Tags: python, influxdb

i got this Dashboard running with influx db:

[image]

is there any way to export my recorded data via python ?

Im very new in influx and would be grateful for any help.

Greetings
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an official influxdb 2.0 python client, https://influxdb-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Here is a simple example to query data to csv file, https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-python/blob/master/examples/query.py